# Shiny progress bar for R in-built functions

Tags: r, shiny

How would one use shiny progress bar for in-built/package functions? My question relates to functions like searchTwitter (as shown in the snippet below) which require tweet number specification making the use of progress bar apt.

```
searchTwitter("search", n = TweetNumber)
```

Comment: maybe you can reformat the question - it is pretty much hard to read/understand

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you want an example of progress without a for-cycle.

Here is one - how to use it for app loadind (defined in server part):

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  withProgress(message = "Application loading", value = 0, {
     #do something
  }
}
```

Comment: This works great. A followup, is it possible to see the gradual progression of the bar if the progress bar is used without a for-loop (as you have defined above)? I am guessing it is not possible since we may not know the progression interval.

Comment: if i understood - yes, it is possible. If you implement resource-demanding app and put withProgress wrapper around it - there is something like progress bar (not standard windows-like - blue thick bar). I'd guess you can even customize it - but I haven't tried it yet

Answer (score 2):

You have to know the progress of your application roughly and set the progress manually. 
Here is some example code:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  withProgress(message = "Application loading", value = 0, {
    # some code
    # ... your code, e.g.:
    Sys.sleep(1)
    # increase progress by 20%
    incProgress(0.2, detail = "Do something")
    #do something
    # ... your code, e.g.:
    Sys.sleep(2)
    # increase 50%
    incProgress(0.5, detail = "Finish something")
    # finish something
    # ... your code
    incProgress(0.3, detail = "Done")
  })
}
```

Comment: This helps a bunch. Thanks!